# SOLVED - IBM AIX : NFS: Value too large to be stored in data type

Tags: ansible, 32bit-64bit, aix, nas

I've got an issue on Continous Deployement step with Ansible playbook for by AIX server.
One tasks on this Ansible playbook is to remove file on NAS with mounted point.
This is the code I used :

```
- name: "Remove NAS files"
  file:
    path: "path_to_remove"
    state: absent
```

However, tasks failed caused : rmtree failed: [Errno 127] Value too large to be stored in data type which issue is detailed in https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/nfs-value-too-large-be-stored-data-type.

My NAS was in 32 bits before and now is in 64bits that why my playbook failed.
I don't understand the solution of IBM support and how to use it in ansible playbook (perhaps shell module and rm -rf command)

Can you help me to find a solution please ?

Comment: Something like this: `ssh somehost "/bin/rm -rf path_to_remove" </dev/null`

Comment: Hello ! I'll try your solution with ansible and shell module : /bin/rm -rf path_to_remove. I'll keep you informed

Comment: Hello ! You got right, your solution work on my ansible playbook :) Thanks a lot